Eliminate customer with less than 2 products from the List
The Power BI report displays customers with a minimum of 2 DS products, as well as those with only 1 DS product. I aim to exclude customers with fewer than 2 products from the list and retain only those with 2 or more products. Could someone assist me in addressing this matter?

I tried the solution below, but it didn't work for me.
DistinctProductCount=COUNTROWS(FILTER(SUMMARIZE(Projects, Projects[Customer Name],"Count_ProductName", COUNT('General Journal Account Entry'[Product Name])),[Count_ProductName] >= 2)


you can try this
MEASURE =
VAR _COUNT =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( GL[Product Name] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( GL ), GL[ProjectID] = MAX ( GL[ProjectID] ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _COUNT >= 2, 1, 0 )



Thanks for your help. This is working for me now.

you can try to create a measure
Measure =
VAR _count =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[product] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[customer] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _count >= 2, 1, 0 )

add that measure to visual filter and set to 1


Thanks for sharing your input, but I've tried this solution and still getting the same result (2 products, as well as 1 product).

could you pls provide the sample data (not the screenshot) or the pbix file?

I have created a sample data and uploaded the pbix file on drive.
Please use below URL to download the pbix file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mZHvkvU4OSBB5RjiI-9aqvFDsJm5MNEO/view?usp=sharing

can't open this. Could you pls upload to onedrive or other website?

I have uploaded the pbix file to the onedrive. Pleas use below URL for your reference.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApIYFheHsqAEabhQrY3Ajgzz85M?e=Ubpv9F
